# Move one row of excel if the next cell is empty

Tags: excel, vb.net

I want to move the one (1) row of excel if the cell of column `F` is empty.

Here is the image of the sample problem.

[image]

please help. thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question - here's the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55389379/edit) - with the code you have tried and why it's not working, thanks!